# Can the coordinate axes be scaled differently in pure math?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, barycentric-coordinates

My question is straightforward. Can the coordinate axes, while being measure by the same unit, be scaled differently (in pure math). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can represent graphically the unit of the $x$ axis and the unit of the $y$ axis with different lengths, if needed.

Comment: Yes. In fact, they can be scaled differently and be at angles other than $90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> When one looks closely, the [modern geometric stance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694962/what-is-fundamentally-a-coordinate-system) is that "scale" is not a _property_ of one set of coordinate axes, but a _relationship_ between two sets of coordinate axes.

Comment: It was quite common in 19th century analytic geometry/conics texts to work with what was called "oblique axes" -- see [this google-books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=analytic+geometry+%22oblique+axes%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899). This wasn't an empty exercise in generality, as the use of non-right angle coordinate systems (with equal axis scaling or otherwise) was sometimes used with great ingenuity in some situations.