# Are Non-Rectangular Coordinate Systems Ever Used?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

In my study of coordinate geometry, I am using the textbook provided by S.L. Loney. In the textbook, he derives various formulas for rectangular coordinates as well as coordinates inclined at a general angle $\omega$. Which makes me ask: is the study of non-rectangular coordinates ever put to use? Is there any profit out of the practice of it? As of now I am merely studying it to further understand the general case of coordinate axes, however, it would be neat if there was actually some case or reason for which non-rectangular are better suited and more comfortable than rectangular coordinates. I could think of one in the area of mathematics alone: to derive formulas more easily. To derive the formula for the area of a hexagon, for example, the oblique axes could be set to be two intersecting sides of the hexagon. So the proof flows much more easier. I would love to hear of more places I can put the knowledges into use. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know polar coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)?

Comment: Barycentric coordinates are oriented along the sides of a triangle. Used in every triangulation of surfaces in computer graphics and triangular meshes as basis for PDE solvers.

Comment: [A] Check out "Oblique Co-Ordinates" & "Curvilinear Co-Ordinates" & "Lorentzian Plane" [B] When the Problem at hand (Physics/Electrical/Mechanical) itself has vectors (Potential/Intensity/velocity/force) along 2 lines , then the Co-Ordinates along those 2 lines will be suitable.

Comment: See [Example of a Problem Made Easier with Skew Coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/837245/13130) and my comment to [Can the coordinate axes be scaled differently in pure math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4517911/13130)

Comment: Non-rectangular coordinates are frequently useful when items are arranged in a non-rectangular grid, for example in drawing a hexagonal tiling in computer graphics.